# ElasticSearch Sorting performance problems

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

**Details**

4-node cluster: 28GB RAM, 4 Cores, 2 512GB SSDs on each
2 - master/data
2- data-only

Using ElasticSearch 1.5.2 (could this be a bug that was since fixed?)

**Summary**

I am trying to debug some issues we are seeing with our cluster responding slow to queries. It has not always been so slow, so we suspected it was just a scale issue (sitting right under 2 billion documents).

However, after some poking around with the index I noticed that our sorting was taking up 99% of the response time.  Here are 2 example queries I have been running. The first is with sorting and the second is without.

**With sorting**

This call takes anywhere from 45 seconds to 60+ seconds (our nginx server timeout is set to 60s and it times out a lot) and only returns 644 documents. This means it appears to take 45+ seconds to sort a mere 644 items

```
POST /backup/entity/_search?routing=3f9d219f-6eef-4880-ad5f-0494492c2fd6
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "entityName.raw": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span class=\"highlighter\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "entityName": {},
      "friendlyUrl": {},
      "sentBy": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": true
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serviceId": "3f9d219f-6eef-4880-ad5f-0494492c2fd6"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionType": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "entityType": [
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

**Without sorting**

This call on the other hand returns in 100-200ms. Same 644 documents, just not sorted.

```
POST /backup/entity/_search?routing=3f9d219f-6eef-4880-ad5f-0494492c2fd6
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 100,
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<span class=\"highlighter\">"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</span>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "entityName": {},
      "friendlyUrl": {},
      "sentBy": {}
    },
    "require_field_match": true
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serviceId": "3f9d219f-6eef-4880-ad5f-0494492c2fd6"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionType": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "entityType": [
              2
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

It seems hard to believe that it is truly taking this long to run a sorting algorithm on these documents.  Even if I inspect all 4 of our nodes at the same time, the CPU and JVM do not ever exceed 60% usage at any given time, so its not like some machine is computing the sort at 100% CPU for all 45+ seconds.  Something else must be going on here.

Comment: What sort of values does entityName.raw consists of? Also, you might want to consider switching to filtered queries this should speed things up since you're not really using scoring anyways.

Comment: [You're probably using fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale).

Comment: @OrWeinberger entityName.raw is just the non-analyzed version of entityName which is just a string name for the document.  Do you think switching the query would actually fix the sorting in any way though?